# Disable automount of second internal drive, to mount it myself

Tags: mount, xubuntu, hard-drive, fstab, automount

For the first time I'm running Xubuntu (Ubunut 16.04 LTS, xenial xerus) with two internal drives.
1) is an SSD with the OS installed on it
2) is an HDD which is supposed to be my storage

I used the standard GUI installer to setup the OS, nothing special at all.

As of this standard Xubuntu installation, the second internal drive (the HDD) is automatically mounted as `1,0 TB Volume` at `/media/<username>/<uuid>`.

Now I would like to know what script does this automount, so that i can undo that and mount it with my prefered name and mountpoint.

I looked in every fstab related file after a `find / -name '*fstab*'` but it's not listed there anywhere.

Where else could this be recorded?

**EDIT:**
To sum up the working solution from the comments:
- I installed gnome-disk-utility (`sudo apt install gnome-disk-utiliy`)
- started it from the terminal with `gnome-disks`
- clicked on the cogwheel icon that says *"Additional partition options"* on hover
- in the popup that shows up I selected *"Edit mount options..."*
- flipped the switch for *"Automatic Mount Options"* to *"Off"*
- and then adjusted the rest to my liking.

So I still don't know where exactly that initial automounting behaviour  is manifested but since it's now configured as I wanted it, I don't mind that to much.

Comment: The file you looking for is `/etc/fstab`

Comment: Nope.  As I said it's not listed there nor any other file related to fstab. That's what exactly what confuses me.

Comment: Is it showing in gparted?

Comment: No.
Only sda1  as ext4  /
and sda2 as exteded which itself then ist partitioned as sda5 swap

Comment: try disk utility

Comment: in disk utility it is listed.
it's also listed when queried `lsblk`

Comment: You can disable automount using disk utility

Comment: you should have added solution as the answer, not the edit to question